# Query how many tasks not completed in period

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a database that tracks the number of tasks completed by staff members and is then signed off by managers. I want to report the number of checklists that are not done in a certain period so the staff using it can complete them. Each checklist is signed off daily but there are none on Saturdays and Sundays. 
So far I have done a query that returns all completed checklists in a period, here is the SQL statement (05/18/2015 being the launch date) -

```
SELECT DISTINCT ChecklistResults.DateofChecklist, ChecklistResults.ClientId
FROM ChecklistResults
WHERE (((ChecklistResults.DateofChecklist)>=#5/18/2015# And ((ChecklistResults.DateofChecklist)<=Forms!Report_Missing!DateCheck)) And ((ChecklistResults.ClientId)=Forms!Report_Missing!ComClientDateChk))
ORDER BY ChecklistResults.DateofChecklist;
```

This shows me all the completed checklists, is there a way of listing all of the dates that have been missed in the period excluding weekends?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One simple method is to exclude those that you've found:

```
Select * From ChecklistResults As T1
Where T1.DateofChecklist >= #5/18/2015# 
    And T1.DateofChecklist <= Forms!Report_Missing!DateCheck 
    And T1.ID Not In 
    (SELECT ID FROM ChecklistResults As T
    WHERE T.DateofChecklist >= #5/18/2015# 
    And T.DateofChecklist <= Forms!Report_Missing!DateCheck 
    And T.ClientId = Forms!Report_Missing!ComClientDateChk)
```

Comment: thanks Gustav but that shows all of the checklists that have been completed except the selected by the controls. My intention is to select the date range with the Forms!Report_Missing!DateCheck button and the client with the ComClientDateChk button. I then want all of the dates that are not completed for this client between the date range to be returned

Comment: Couldn't you just apply the filter on the these also? Edited my answer to show this.

Comment: doesnt seem to work. Ive tried something else - I created an array of dates between two selections on two text boxes. I then loop through the array and if any of the dates are not in the query I generate them in a text box.

Comment: Array? I removed the filter for ClientId from the top select to list result from all clients.